# Windows Forms app with AutoWaitCursor - crashing in VS2013CE debugger if platform is x64 or ANY CPU

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

I have created a a minimal Windows Forms project that I added AutoWaitCursor to demonstrate the problem at https://github.com/rluiten/WinForm-AutoWaitCursor-Problem

Please note AutoWaitCursor is no longer available at the original link I got it from which was http://www.vbusers.com/codecsharp/codeget.asp?ThreadID=58&PostID=1&NumReplies=0

If I launch this Windows Forms Project inside Visual Studio with the Debugger and platform at "Any CPU" or "x64" on my 64 bit Windows 7 PC I get a "vshost.exe has stopped working" dialog appear and the application has crashed.

Launching with Debugger and with platform set to "x86" is not a problem. Launching without the Debugger is not a problem for any platform. Launching resultant compiled binary outside Visual Studio has not yet exhibited a related problem.

It appears to be a coupling of AutoWaitCursor and Visual Studio 2013 Debugger and 64bit mode. I believe currently that VS2012 which I have used in the past did not exhibit this behaviour but I cannot verify that at the moment. While this problem is not a show stopper.

I would like to understand or fix the issue but have not made any progress in that direction yet.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I am using code originally from http://www.emoticode.net/c-sharp/automatically-showing-a-wait-cursor-to-indicate-a-long-operation-is-occurring.html.
GetCurrentThreadId(), AttachThreadInput(), SendMessageTimeout() are the only API functions involved. Does the 64-bit debugger do anything special with those functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the signature for SendMessageTimeout, change the int and string(!) parameters to IntPtr.

In _IsApplicationBusy, change result to be IntPtr; use IntPtr for the parameters you changed in the API signature; last line should be return result != IntPtr.Zero;

Test everything is working by using your github app, dropping a button onto the form and running Thread.Sleep(3000); in a Click handler.

Comment: I get the problem even without adding a button with the Thread.Sleep. Your suggestion appears to fix things. As a test, I changed just the String parameter and the Out parameter to IntPtr and the problem also does not occur (that is without converting all the normal parameters to IntPtr as well). Thanks for the input, I am curious how you got to the solution ?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I went looking further and checked here http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SendMessageTimeout which also works - and might be more correct Cheers!

Comment: Putting a breakpoint on all the API calls found it was SendMessageTimeout that was the issue. Various webpages had different definitions (including the one you mention) so I just changed them to the simplest thing that worked. Since they were just 0 checks ultimately IntPtr was good enough.

Comment: One other point: whilst playing with this I found my app wasn't crashing anymore but the AutoWaitCursor wasn't working (hence me adding a button with Thread.Sleep in both your and my app). Turns out that my AutoWaitCursor was disposing itself as my Splashform closed and before the main form had even shown itself. Changing the event listened to from Application.ThreadExit to Application.ApplicationExit fixed that.